# SwiftUI when can i use if statement in result builder?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I notice that sometimes I am able to use if-else statement in SwiftUI's result builder just fine. For example, inside a body:

```
struct MyView: View {
  var body: some View {
    if foo {
      Text("foo")
    } 
  }
}
```

However, sometimes I can't, for example, inside view modifier:

```
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .toolbar {
        if foo { Button("foo") {} }
      }
    }
  }
```

This above gives me error saying:

```
Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ToolbarContentBuilder'
```

This is so confusing. Why are they different? When can I use if-else, and when it should be avoided (and in that case, why is it bad? and what should I do? )

Edit:

I tried to put the button under a `Group {}` under the toolbar. It's not working either:

```
      .toolbar {
        Group {
          if true { // can't put if here
            Button("foo")
```

Got this error:

```
Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'CommandsBuilder'
```

Comment: `ViewBuilder` has `buildIf` implementation, but `ToolbarContentBuilder` does not have. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ToolbarContentBuilder does not allow if statements, it's designed to use `ToolbarItemGroup`, where you can use if like a regular ViewBuilder:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    if foo { Button("foo") {} }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and got ```Generic struct 'ToolbarItemGroup' requires that 'ToolbarItem<Void, Button<Text>>' conform to 'View'```

Comment: Ah I think I put another `ToolbarItem` under `ToolbarItemGroup`. What you have is correct

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI uses [`ResultBuilder`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md) to build views.  John Sundell has a good [deep-dive](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/deep-dive-into-swift-function-builders/) article on them.

Whether you can use an `if` depends on the result builders used by the view and, specifically, whether it implements `buildIf`/[`buildOptional`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md) methods.

An implication of supporting `if` in a result builder is that there can be 0 views in the result.

For whatever reason, the implementers of `toolbar` have decided that there must be some content in a toolbar and the so result builder they have used [`ToolBarContentBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbarcontentbuilder) does not implement the required methods to support conditional statements.

You are right, it is a little confusing.  Unfortunately the only ways to find out whether conditionals are supported in a particular context is try or to read through the documentation to find the result builder that an element uses.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: Steve M's solution worked for me